# ParseException: SQL CTE

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks, common-table-expression, databricks-sql

```py
result = aml_identity_g.connectedComponents()
conn_comps = result.select("id", "component",'type') \
  .createOrReplaceTempView("components") 
display(result)
```

Which creates

[image]

```
%sql
create table temptable 
as with dupes as (
   select component, count(case when type = 'Person' then 1 end) person_ct 
   from components 
   group by component 
   having person_ct > 1
)
```

Throws me an error as

```
Error in SQL statement: ParseException: 
mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting {'(', 'DESC', 'DESCRIBE', 'FROM', 'MAP', 'REDUCE', 'SELECT', 'TABLE', 'VALUES'}(line 6, pos 21)
   
== SQL ==
create table temptable 
as with dupes as (
    select component, count(case when type = 'Person' then 1 end) 
person_ct 
    from components 
    group by component 
    having person_ct > 1
)
---------------------^^^
```

Don't understand the error here.

Comment: maybe add `SELECT * FROM dupes` at the end?

Comment: Hi, you cannot use an alias name in having a clause. Try using same count expression instead of person_ct.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need CTE in this query - it should be enough to have normal `SELECT`. So it should be something like this:

```sql
create table temptable as (
   select component, count(case when type = 'Person' then 1 end) person_ct 
   from components 
   group by component 
   having person_ct > 1
)
```

P.S. According to [documentation on HAVING clause](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-having.html) you can use alias in the `HAVING` expression.